# How to solve illegal instruction (core dump) in training the model using Tensorflow version 2.5.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, arm64

I am using linux aarch64 architecture. I built miniconda3 and create a virtual environment in miniconda3.
I installed tensorflow 2.5.0 via conda.
When I train the model, I got illegal instruction (core dump).

May I know how can I solve the issue?
May I know does aarch64 architecture needs to do some modification in Tensorflow when training the model?

Edit : include more information about linux machine

My linux machine's CPU does not have AVX instructions. CPU features include `fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32`

Comment: Did you build the virtual environment on an x64 machine and then copy it to your aarch64 machine?  The virtual environment includes DLLs that must be built on the target architecture.

Comment: Note this:  https://github.com/KumaTea/tensorflow-aarch64

Comment: @Tim Roberts, I build virtual environment in aarch64 machine after installing miniconda3 installer in aarch64 machine.

Comment: @TimRoberts, my machine's CPU does not have AVX instructions.

Comment: Of course not; AVX is an Intel thing, not an ARM thing.  Did you check out that link?  It has Python wheels for tensorflow for aarch64.

Comment: Yes I also installed with ```conda install -c kumatea tensorflow```. When I run the script, it gives ```Illegal Instruction (core dumped)```. When I tried  ```pip install tensorflow-cpu -f https://tf.kmtea.eu/whl/stable.html```, I got ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-cpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-cpu
```.

Comment: Is my cpu using older version of CPU?

Comment: @TimRoberts, in the other websites, it mentioned that tensorflow version 2.* can be used with AVX instruction. I am not sure how to use tensorflow without getting illegal instruction in aarch64 architecture.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I also tried to downgraded tensorflow from 2.5.0 to 1.5.0 ```pip install tensorflow==1.5.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5.0 (from versions: 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.5.0
```, I got no matching distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep bringing up AVX.  The AVX instructions are part of the Intel CPUs (x86 and x64).  They are not part of the ARM world, which is what you have. TensorFlow has many components that have to be compiled from C.  You HAVE to get versions compiled for your processor.  You may need to ask the TensorFlow forums for help.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, Because in this website, it mentions to check whether it support AVX and if not it is needed to install tensorflow 1.5 or compile the tensorflow using bazel. https://tech.amikelive.com/node-887/how-to-resolve-error-illegal-instruction-core-dumped-when-running-import-tensorflow-in-a-python-program/

Comment: BUT those comments only apply to Intel processors!!!  You can't use ANY distribution that includes Intel binaries.  You are in a special and very limited world.  You have to DIG to find a package that works on ARM.